# Parameter Mapping using an Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temporary table and insert data into the temp table within an Execute SQL Task inside a foreach loop container.

Here are the sql tasks

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP
GO

CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
      ( ... );

INSERT INTO #TEMP
      SELECT (...)
  FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
WHERE t1.value = ?
```

I want to have a parameter in the WHERE clause but whenever I try to add it I get this error.

"Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

When I hard code the value in the Where Clause the insert works perfectly.

**What am I doing wrong on my parameter mapping?**

Here are my parameter mapping settings 
[image]

*Also I am not able to use a stored procedure.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to `Expressions` Tab as shown in the  screenshot **you provided** and write the following expression to `SqlStatmentSource` property

```
"IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP
GO

CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
      ( ... );

INSERT INTO #TEMP
      SELECT (...)
  FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
WHERE t1.value = '"  +  @[User::Where_Variable]  +   "'"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot and I got it working. I ended up having to move the drop statement to a separate sql task.

Comment: @DericPlummer happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Populate a variable with your entire SQL script, and use the variable as your SQLSourceType in your Execute SQL Task.