# SSIS Evaluate expression containing arithmetic

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I can't quite find the answer to this. How can I evaluate an expression that contains arithmetic in SSIS. Specifically within a variable's expression field or in the Execute SQL task -> SQL statement as expression.

I have a user defined variable 'Width' that is assigned to a variable as type decimal. `388.00`

and I have another variable `Range` as type decimal.
I need to create a dynamic sql statement but I need these values to evaluate using the following:

```
@[User::Width] - @[User::Range]
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: In execute sql task you use a question mark for parameters.  The ? is replaced based on the parameter order.  So it might look like ? - ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable as a parameter in Execute SQL Task SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610491/how-to-pass-variable-as-a-parameter-in-execute-sql-task-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Expressions** to achieve this.

1. Double click on  the `Execute SQL Task`
2. GoTo Expression Tab
3. Select the `SqlStatmentSource` Property
4. Write the expression you want, example:

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable
   WHERE [quantity] = " + (DT_WSTR,50)(@[User::Width] - @[User::Range])
   ```

*You can check my asnwer at [Parameter Mapping using an Execute SQL Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463428/parameter-mapping-using-an-execute-sql-task/44482771#44482771) (similar case)*